# Trouble looping with 'for' and 'while'

Tags: c, loops

I wanted a program that reads two words from the user and prints the number of occurrences of the second word in the first one.

When I write with `for` loop it works exactly as I want but when I write with `while` loop and  try with a specific input, it does not give the correct result. I couldn't figure out why. Code snippets are below.

with `for` loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char text[200], search[20];
    int i, j, count = 0;
    scanf("%s %s", text, search);
    for (i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (j = 0; search[j] != '\0' && search[j] == text[i + j]; j++) {
        }
        if (search[j] == '\0') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", count);
}
```

with `while` loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char word[50], search[50];
    int i, j, count = 0;
    scanf("%s %s", word, search);
    i = 0;
    while (word[i] != '\0') {
        j = 0;
        while (search[j] != '\0' && search[j] == word[i + j]) {
            j++;                
        }
        if (search[j] == '\0') {
            count++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", count);
}
```

and input that works with `for` loop but does not give the correct result with `while` loop:

```
athousandyearsofthousandtimesandinthousandplacesOand... and
```

it should print `4` but it prints `3026483`.

Comment: Is your spacebar broken?  Also, failing to check the return value of `scanf()` is bad.

Comment: Your input looks longer than 49 characters

Comment: You didn't just change the for loops to while loops though. You also changed `text[200]` to `word[50]` and `search[20]` to `search[50]`.

Comment: They say `int main(void)` is better than `int main()`

Answer (score 4):

The `for` logic and the `while` logic are both correct.  The problem is in the size of your input buffer.

In the first program `text` is 200 characters, while in the second `word` is 50 characters.  Your input string is 55 characters long, so it overruns your input buffer leading to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Make the input buffer in the second program larger and it should work fine.